# Android Emulator issues on CentOS 6 using Jenkins plugin

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator

I have configured android emulator on linux virtual machine which has CentOS 6.10, but I can't seem to run the emulator. The log bellow I get also in console output when building from Jenkins.
I tried to run the emulator both from `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator` and `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator`

```
 [root@Jenkins_Payment tools]# ./emulator @android-test-emulator
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.3.4' not found (required by ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5GuiAndroidEmu.so.5)
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel: /usr/lib64/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.22' not found (required by ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.so.5)
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.so.5)
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-armel: /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so: version `NSSUTIL_3.17.1' not found (required by ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libsoftokn3.so)
```

This are the files that I already have installed.

```
[root@Jenkins_Payment lib64]# ls /lib64 | grep libz.so.1
libz.so.1
libz.so.1.2.3
[root@Jenkins_Payment lib64]# ls /usr/lib64/ | grep libnss3.so
libnss3.so
[root@Jenkins_Payment lib64]# ls /lib64 | grep libdbus-1.so.3
libdbus-1.so.3
libdbus-1.so.3.4.0
[root@Jenkins_Payment lib64]# ls /usr/lib64/ | grep libnssutil3.so
libnssutil3.so
[root@Jenkins_Payment lib64]#
```

I'am really clueless of how can i resolve this.

Also this is the android emulator I am trying to run

```
Running /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/avdmanager list avd

Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: android-test-emulator
    Path: /root/.android/avd/android-test-emulator.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) Tag/ABI: google_apis/armeabi-v7a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built zlib and dbus from source with newer versions. CentOS 6 doesn't have update from yum repos. And updated nss and nss-utils from CentOS 6 update repo.